# Enforce CRUD on single record DML statement

Tags: apex, security, dml, crud

As the title suggests I am trying to enforce CRUD on a DML statement for a single record. I see the stripInaccessible() method takes in a list of sObjects. Is there an equivalent method for a single record? Or do I need to add my single record to a list before the check?

Comment: Either add it to a list and call `stripInaccessible`, or apply your own tests before the DML using the Schema API. It depends on whether you want the DML to be allowed, with a partial update of the record, or you want to disallow the DML entirely.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW I had a feeling that was the case! Thanks again for confirming.